Which packet provides /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so?
I'm compiling a 32 bit program on 64 bit ubuntu 22.04 with clang.
The linker fails with /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory.
There is no file/no symlink at /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so (see search paths below).
If I manually create a link like so sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so, it compiles successfully.
Now I wonder if there is any package that provides a symlink or do I need other parameters?
Thanks for your help.

This is the verbose clang output:
/usr/bin/clang -o test test.pic.o stub.pic.o libutest.a libmain.a \
    -lm -lstdc++ \
    --target=i386-linux-gnu \
    -v
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: i386-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Candidate multilib: x32;@mx32
Selected multilib: 32;@m32
 "/usr/bin/ld" -pie -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o test /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib32/Scrt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib32/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gc
c/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/32/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/32 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib32 -L/lib/../lib32 -L/usr/l
ib/../lib32 -L/usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib --whole-archive /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan_static-i386.a --no-whole-arch
ive --whole-archive /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-i386.a --no-whole-archive --export-dynamic test.pic.o stub.pic.o libutest.a libmain.a -lm -lstdc++ --no-as-needed -lpthread -lrt -lm -ldl -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/bin/../lib
/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/32/crtendS.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib32/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory

Search paths normalised:
/lib
/lib32
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/32
/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib
/usr/lib32


Package lib32stdc++6 provides the actual 32-bit library ex. /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.30 however if clang is using GNU ld as the linker it will expect to find a symbolic link /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/NN/32/libstdc++.so where NN is the GCC version selected by clang. This link is provided by the corresponding lib32stdc++-NN-dev package.
So given
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11

you would need to install lib32stdc++6 and lib32stdc++-11-dev. However it is probably better to install the g++-multilib dependency package, which will install the packages for the default compiler (i.e. gcc-11) automatically.

Yes, worked, thank you! g++-multilib created this link: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/32/libstdc++.so -> ../../../../../lib32/libstdc++.so.6
